# Why boolean type can get `undefined` in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
const boo : boolean = undefined
```

In typescript, Above code do not throw error.
I wonder the reason.

Comment: Um... For me, that results in a *"Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. (2322)"* compilation error.

Comment: Did you enable the `strictNullChecks` or `strict` compiler option?

Comment: `strict: false` or `strictNullChecks: false` in tsconfig.json will allow it to compile, and the resulting JS would be `const boo = undefined` which will not throw any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to defined it as a union to allow your `boolean` to be `undefined`

```
const boo : boolean | undefined = undefined
```

See [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) which rules on this.